# Showing $f:a\to b$ is epic iff there exists some iso $g: f(a)\cong b$ with $g\circ f^*=f$.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

This is [Exercise 5.2.4](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLPDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=%22is+epic+iff+there+exists%22&source=bl&ots=qRfIIY0PNh&sig=kTJKUR_8r5Xi1jXHe2AM3i-MfYs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O2KpU-GKD8OsPNrYgJAJ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20epic%20iff%20there%20exists%22&f=false) of Goldblatt's, "*Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic*".

In any topos, given $f:a\to b$, define $p, q: b\to r$ using the pullback of $f$ along itself like so $$\begin{array}{ccc}a&\stackrel{f}{\to}&b \\ f\downarrow & & \downarrow q \\ b& \stackrel{p}{\to}& r,\end{array}$$ $\operatorname{im}f: f(a)\rightarrowtail b$ as the equalizer of $p$ and $q$ (known to be monic), and $f^*:a\dashrightarrow f(a)$ as the unique arrow given by the equalizer $\operatorname{im}f$ so that $f=\operatorname{im}f\circ f^*$.

> **Fact 1:** $f^*$ is epic.

This follows from **Theorem 1**, ibid., p. 112.

> Show that $(a)$ $f:a\to b$ is epic iff $(b)$ there exists some iso $g: f(a)\cong b$ with $g\circ f^*=f$.

*Thoughts:* I've shown $(b)\implies (a)$ by assuming $(b)$ and supposing there exist $h, \ell$ with $k\circ f=\ell\circ f$, so that $(k\circ g)\circ f^*=(\ell\circ g)\circ f^*$ gives $k=\ell$ since $f^*$ is epic and $g$ is iso.

But I'm stuck showing $(a)\implies (b)$. If $f$ is epic, then $p=q$. $\color{red}{\text{If }}g$ exists, then $$g\circ f^*=f=\operatorname{im}f\circ f^*,$$ so $g=\operatorname{im}f$. So perhaps I just need to find the inverse of $\operatorname{im}f$, right? I don't know what to do next.

I've formed the pullback of $f$ along $\operatorname{im}f$. That was pointless.

Please help :)

---

*NB:* **Theorem 2**, ibid., p. 114, might be required.

Comment: If $f$ is epic, you have found $p=q$. Then $\operatorname{im}f$ is defined as the equalizer of $p$ and $q$. So what is the equalizer of two identical arrows ?

Comment: It's iso! Thank you, @Pece! Would you like to post that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is epic, then $p=q$ as you said.

Now, $\operatorname{im}f$ is defined as the equalizer of $p,q \colon b \rightrightarrows r$.

> **Fact.** In any category $\mathscr C$, and for any arrow $h\colon x\to y$ in $\mathscr C$, the equalizer of
>   $$
> x \overset h{\underset h \rightrightarrows} y
> $$
>   exists and is $\operatorname{id}_x \colon x \to x.$

(Just check it !)

So here $\operatorname{im}f$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{id}_b$ (in the category of arrows of your topos). It gives the wanted isomorphism $g \colon f(a) \simeq b$.